# SNR calculation by python (verified code by TI ADS7042 EVM)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, texas-instruments

I have obtained 12-bit ADC output data from the TI ADS7042 EVM kit.
I am trying to calculate the SNR, THDm, SINAD (in dB), and other parameters.
The output code ranges from 0 to 4095.
[ADC-output2.txt](https://i.fluffy.cc/VfvCSTdR4lS1n3R9Q9jmJsj9QZVRpjjg.txt)

I use the below code to check the SNR and THD.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io
def preprocess_adc_data(adc_data, v_ref, adc_resolution):
    adc_data_np = np.array(adc_data)
    adc_data_np = adc_data_np - np.mean(adc_data_np)  # 

    # 7 term Blackman-Harris window
    window = signal.windows.blackmanharris(len(adc_data_np))
    adc_data_np = adc_data_np * window

    return (adc_data_np / (2 ** adc_resolution - 1)) * v_ref


def estimate_input_frequency_from_spectrum(adc_data_voltage, fs):
    # Spectrum Calculate
    f, Pxx = signal.periodogram(adc_data_voltage, fs)

    # Find the frequency corresponding to the maximum value in the power spectrum.
    max_index = np.argmax(Pxx)
    frequency = f[max_index]

    return frequency

def calculate_snr(adc_data_voltage, fs):
    f, Pxx = signal.periodogram(adc_data_voltage, fs)
    snr = 10 * np.log10(np.max(Pxx) / (np.sum(Pxx) - np.max(Pxx)))
    return snr

def plot_signal(adc_data_voltage, fs):
    t = np.arange(len(adc_data_voltage)) / fs
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(t, adc_data_voltage)
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
    plt.title('Restored Signal Waveform')
    plt.show()

def plot_spectrum(adc_data_voltage, fs, f_input):
    nfft = int(fs)
    f, Pxx = signal.periodogram(adc_data_voltage, fs, nfft=nfft)
    Pxx_dBc = 10 * np.log10(Pxx / np.max(Pxx))
    # Maximum frequency
    f_limit = 1e5
    idx = np.where(f <= f_limit)
    f_limited = f[idx]
    Pxx_dBc_limited = Pxx_dBc[idx]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(f_limited, Pxx_dBc_limited)
    ax.set_xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
    ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude (dBC)")
    ax.set_title("Spectrum")

    # Limit X-axis and Y-axis
    ax.set_xlim([0, f_limit])
    ax.set_ylim([-160, 20])

    # Compute the fundamental frequency and harmonics.
    fundamental_freq = int(f_input)
    first_harmonic_freq = 2 * fundamental_freq
    second_harmonic_freq = 3 * fundamental_freq
    third_harmonic_freq = 4 * fundamental_freq

    # Locate the positions of the fundamental frequency and harmonics in the spectrum.
    fundamental_idx = np.where(f == fundamental_freq)
    first_harmonic_idx = np.where(f == first_harmonic_freq)
    second_harmonic_idx = np.where(f == second_harmonic_freq)
    third_harmonic_idx = np.where(f == third_harmonic_freq)

    # Extract the dBc values of the fundamental frequency and harmonics.
    fundamental_dBc = float(Pxx_dBc[fundamental_idx])
    first_harmonic_dBc = float(Pxx_dBc[first_harmonic_idx])
    second_harmonic_dBc = float(Pxx_dBc[second_harmonic_idx])
    third_harmonic_dBc = float(Pxx_dBc[third_harmonic_idx])

    print("H1：{:.0f} Hz, {:.2f} dBc".format(fundamental_freq, fundamental_dBc))
    print("H2：{:.0f} Hz, {:.2f} dBc".format(first_harmonic_freq, first_harmonic_dBc))
    print("H3：{:.0f} Hz, {:.2f} dBc".format(second_harmonic_freq, second_harmonic_dBc))
    print("H4：{:.0f} Hz, {:.2f} dBc".format(third_harmonic_freq, third_harmonic_dBc))

    plt.show()



def read_adc_data_from_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    adc_data = [int(line.strip()) for line in lines]
    return adc_data


def calculate_thdn(adc_data_voltage, fs, fundamental_frequency, num_harmonics=7):
    f, Pxx = signal.periodogram(adc_data_voltage, fs)

    fundamental_power = None
    harmonics_power = 0

    for harmonic in range(1, num_harmonics + 1):
        harmonic_frequency = fundamental_frequency * harmonic
        index = np.argmin(np.abs(f - harmonic_frequency))
        power = Pxx[index]

        if harmonic == 1:
            fundamental_power = power
        else:
            harmonics_power += power

    thdn = np.sqrt(harmonics_power / fundamental_power)
    thdn_db = 20 * np.log10(thdn)
    return thdn_db


file_path = './ADC-output2.txt'  # File
adc_data = read_adc_data_from_file(file_path)


v_ref = 3.3
adc_resolution = 12
adc_data_voltage = preprocess_adc_data(adc_data, v_ref, adc_resolution)
sample_rate = 1e6  # 1 MHz

f_input = estimate_input_frequency_from_spectrum(adc_data_voltage, sample_rate)
print("Estimated input frequency: {:.2f} Hz".format(f_input))

# Plot the reconstructed signal waveform and the spectral analysis waveform.
plot_signal(adc_data_voltage, sample_rate)
plot_spectrum(adc_data_voltage, sample_rate, f_input)
# SNR
snr = calculate_snr(adc_data_voltage, sample_rate)
print("SNR: {:.2f} dB".format(snr))
# THD
thdn = calculate_thdn(adc_data_voltage, sample_rate, f_input)
print("THD+N: {:.2f} dB".format(thdn))
```

From the TI EVM kit, the result is as below:
[The result from TI software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BDFH.png)

The result of my code shows below:
H1：10009 Hz, -0.00 dBc
H2：20018 Hz, -80.43 dBc
H3：30027 Hz, -86.12 dBc
H4：40036 Hz, -91.65 dBc
SNR: -0.03 Hz
THD+N: -77.97 dB
[And the Specturm from Python calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0buf.png)

Significant differences are observed in the calculated results for SNR.
Please kindly help me identify what's wrong with the code?
Thank

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of SNR is taking whole spectrum (minus single spectrum sample) as a denominator, treating it as a noise.

```
snr = 10 * np.log10(np.max(Pxx) / (np.sum(Pxx) - np.max(Pxx)))
```

The signal is not a single sample in spectrum domain, it is quite wide. Your algorithm assumes almost all of it is noise (all except single sample) and thats why SNR is so small.

Calculating SNR is usually a bit arbitrary thing to do. It depends on the signals you are measuring. If you want to have 1-to-1 correspondence you could ask Texas Instruments how they calculate it. Maybe this is not a secret.